# Alert inside window.load function is not working

Tags: javascript

Why the window onload code  doesn't work;

```
window.onload = function(){
    var pix = 5;
     alert(pix)
};
```

I also tried with global variable

```
var pix;
window.onload = function(){
    pix = 5;
    alert(pix);
};
```

The above two code doesn't alert anything

suppose i put alert outside it alerts "undefined"

I expect alert should give 5; Anybody explain what does happen here

[**My Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/us9swrx1/)

Comment: Does this happen in `jsfiddle` only?

Comment: Where are you running that code from? If you set an `.onload` handler *after* the onload event has occurred then the handler won't run. Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/us9swrx1/3/ - same thing, except without jsfiddle's default of wrapping the JS in an onload handler of its own.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9899372/pure-javascript-equivalent-to-jquerys-ready-how-to-call-a-function-when-the

Comment: [It is working](http://jsfiddle.net/us9swrx1/9/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this happens in [`jsfiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/) only, you've used `onLoad` option to execute your script. This means, your code is already inside `onload` event. And your `onload` handler will not work.

To solve this issue, change the script location to `No wrap` in `<head>` or `<body>` from the left options on *jsfiddle*.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/us9swrx1/1/)

Answer (score 0):

When onfocus doesn't work try

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var blah = 4;
    alert(blah);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I am asking about window onload I very well know about document ready :p

Comment: well, you did tag jQuery.

Comment: Jquery users also know javascript as well that why  I am tagged